# Define struct from void address

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void

Actually what i want to do is to use different structs in same function with same parameter.

Code:

```
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    int r;
}Circle;

typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
}Point;

int collisionCircleVsCircle(Circle c1, Circle c2){
    if(c1.r + c2.r >= sqrt((c1.x - c2.x)*(c1.x - c2.x) + (c1.y - c2.y)*(c1.y - c2.y))) return 1;
return 0;
}

int collisionPointVsCircle(Point p, Circle c){
    if(c.r >= sqrt((p.x - c.x)*(p.x - c.x) + (p.y - c.y)*(p.y - c.y))) return 1;
     return 0;
}

typedef struct{
     int id;
     void *ptr;
}Body;


int collisionBody(Body b1, Body b2){};
```

I defined a new struct to do what i mentioned above(Body). But how do i give the address information to the Circle and Point (in collisionBody function)?

Do you have a better way?

Does it have a type() function like in interpreted languages?

For example:

```
Circle circle1;

printf type(circle1);

-->Circle
```

Comment: No, C doesn't have any runtime type information. There's no built-in way to know what a pointer points to.

Comment: Use a discriminated union.

Comment: There are better ways, use `_Generic` from C11 to dispatch types on compilation time. The question should be reopened